# No bean named 'dispatch' is defined

Tags: java, eclipse, gwtp

Running a `gwtp-sample-basic-spring` app in Eclipse, I see the welcome page, but after some server processing I get the following (and, probably, it's like that [not only on my machine](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=44#c62)):

```
[WARN] /dispatch/
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dispatch' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.init(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:342)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /dispatch/ (127.0.0.1) 3790 bytes
```

Why can I get this error? Everything's fine when running without Eclipse. Spring libraries are included in the classpath with a help of maven dependencies, as well as all the other needed.

Comment: Are there any strange warning/errors during the Spring initialisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a [nice tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/RunningGwtpSamples) about running these samples, but one step is missed there and as an Eclipse newbie I had this trouble. At first in `Project properties/ Google/ Web application/ War directory` I set `src/main/webapps`, which was wrong and needed libraries where in classpath, but coudn't work properly. Setting `War directory` to `target/gwpt-spring-0.6` solved the problem.